# NSDictionary to XML String

Tags: xml, nsdictionary

Im using XML communication between Iphone and Java server. Using TBXml I parse incoming messages. Whats a good method to convert NSDictionary to xmlString?

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me:

```
NSString *error;
NSData *xmlData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList: myDictionary
                                                             format: NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                   errorDescription: &error];

NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: xmlData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary consists of a limited number of classes, specifically `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDate`, and `NSNumber`, you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization`, in particular the `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` method.  This will write out the data in plist XML, which is sufficient for simple cases.

Otherwise, you will probably have to write custom serialization methods for custom classes.

Comment: It would be wonderful if this method existed in NSPropertyListSerialization.

Comment: @mpemburn -- I wasn't clear: `-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` is a method on NSDictionary that uses property list serialization, thus the same rules.